# Discord.js | TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I'm working on a discord.js bot and its giving me a TypeError, but I'm not sure why.
Code:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'kick',
description: 'Tag a member and kick them',
execute(message) {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
        message.channel.send("You're not an admin lmaooo")
        return;
    };

    let mentionMember = message.mentions.members.first();

    if(!mentionMember){
        message.channel.send("Who do you want me to kick :smiling_imp:")
        return;
    }

    let authorHighestRole = message.member.highestRole.position;
    let mentionHighestRole = mentionMember.highestRole.position;

    if(mentionHighestRole >= authorHighesrRole) {
        message.channel.send("I can't kick him hes to op :tired_fac:")
        return;
    };

    if(!mentionMember.kickable){
        message.channel.send("I have no perms cant kick him lol")
    };

    mentionMember.kick()
        .then(() => console.log(`Kicked ${member.displayName}`))
        .catch(console.error);
},
```

};

Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify what you're trying to code.

Node.js usually provides the line where the error has occurred.

Check `if (mentionHighestRole >= authorHighesrRole) {`
It probably should be `authorHighestRole`.
If that doesn't solve the issue, then it's probably the if statement itself, because that statement doesn't make sense to me.

EDIT: your `authorHighestRole` should also be `let authorHighestRole = message.author.highestRole.position`.